# c++ #define and concatenate case (I am using gcc)

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have

```
#define NAME(value) my ## value ## value
```

when I do `NAME(1)`, it is `my1value`, which is good!

But I want to pass variable into `NAME()`,
such as

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    NAME(i);
    ...
}
```

But unfortunately, it becomes `myivalue`, but I want `my0value`, `my1value` etc.

What should I change?
Thanks

Comment: macro does simple replacement.

Comment: `when I do NAME(1), it is my1value, which is good!` I'm pretty sure that it's not `my1value`.

Comment: You are confusing compile-time and execution-time values. The value of `i` is (formally) only known at execution-time, but the preprocessor can only deal with things during compile-time. Actually, as mentioned by @SongWang, it's even a "dumb" phase before compilation, which can only read the source code as words without meaning: it simply replaces tokens such as `NAME`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement an array with the preprocessor. Why?

Comment: (By the way, don't downvote this question because you think it's stupid. It's an understandable mistake, for instance, for people who previously only used dynamic languages.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros are substituted at compile-time (actually, they are substituted by the preprocessr even before "real" compilation begins), and it's pure **text** processing.

You cannot expect your macro to compute its expansion based on the value of a *variable*.

Answer (score 1):

Macros only do text-replacement before compiling. It's basically the same as doing a 'Find&Replace' over your code. Loops are executed at runtime - so this doesn't make any sense.

But to answer your question anyway .... you could use a (compile-time) macro 'loop':

```
#include <iostream>

#define NAME(v) my##v##value
#define LOOP10 NAME(0), NAME(1), NAME(2), NAME(3), NAME(4), NAME(5), NAME(6), NAME(7), NAME(8), NAME(9)


int main()
{
    int LOOP10;    // example usage
}
```

boost supports preprocessor loops, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

**##** is a pre-processor directive

*##* concatenates what's before the  **##**  with what's after it in the #define statement

As u said **"#define NAME(value) my ## value ## value"** this becomes an error.it means "myii" not myivalue